# how to set camera to the same view as I turn my cursor?

Tags: camera

I want to turn the camera to get the view I want, but everytime I turn the camera, I need to go to render window to check if it's the view I want. I turn the view with my mouse cursor, but that does not affect the actual camera view in rendering, can I set the camera view the same as I turn my cursor?

Answer (score 4):

You can enable camera lock, so your camera moves as you're looking through it.

Check it in *Sidebar > View > Lock Camera to View*
Then press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to view through your camera.
Now just move, zoom and your camera will exactly follow.

[image]

You can switch it on and off as you like.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set your viewport the way you want it and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad0</kbd>, this will do following: set camera to fit your view, set your view to the camera.

Another way, would be to select camera, press <kbd>NumPad0</kbd>, this will set your current view to camera, and any changes to camera's position/rotation will be instantly visible on the screen.